# Adding an integer to a label for diplay purposes

Tags: c#

how do I add an integer, ie. a count variable for displaying purposes?

```
int counter = 0;
    private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader("StudentRecords.txt");

        while (myReader.EndOfStream == false)
        {
            string[] storageArray = myReader.ReadLine().Split('#');
            if (storageArray[0] == "S")
            {
                lstDisplay.Items.Add("");
                lstDisplay.Items.Add("Student Name: " + storageArray[1]);
                lstDisplay.Items.Add("Student Number: " +storageArray[2]);
                lstDisplay.Items.Add("Attendance: " + storageArray[5]);
                lstDisplay.Items.Add("Modules: ");
                counter++;
            }
            else if (storageArray[0] == "M")
            {
                lstDisplay.Items.Add(storageArray[1]);

            }

        }

        //label to be used to display the number of students
        lblnoOfStudents. ??
        myReader.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Consider looking at my edited answer andre to learn a couple of other ways you could improve your function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lblnoOfStudents.Text = counter.ToString();
```

That will change text on the label to that number. If you'd like to append it at the end of existing text use `+=`:

```
lblnoOfStudents.Text += counter.ToString();
```

Comment: @AndreSmith - the second won't work as expected if you click display button twice

Comment: No Worries, i used the first one... its all i needed anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Assign your message to `Text` property of your label:

```
lblnoOfStudents.Text = string.Format("Students: {0}", counter);
```

Comment: As a side note: `string.Format` will replace `{0}` with `counter` variable value, so it will result in something like `Students: 1024`

Comment: And if you want to get rid of the *something like*, pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as the first argument to `Format()`. That way you won't end up with `1,024`, `1 024` or similar instead of `1024`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.text.aspx) property of your `Label` control. Like;

> Gets or sets the text content of the Label control.

```
lblnoOfStudents.Text = counter.ToString();
```

This will change your label text with string representation of your `counter` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Heres aworking example for your code

```
//int counter = 0; may as well move inside as it looks to be localised
private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader("StudentRecords.txt");
    int counter = 0;
    while (myReader.EndOfStream == false)
    {
        string[] storageArray = myReader.ReadLine().Split('#');
        if (storageArray[0] = "S")
        {
            lstDisplay.Items.Add("");
            lstDisplay.Items.Add("Student Name: " + storageArray[1]);
            lstDisplay.Items.Add("Student Number: " +storageArray[2]);
            lstDisplay.Items.Add("Attendance: " + storageArray[5]);
            lstDisplay.Items.Add("Modules: ");
            counter++;
        }
        else if (storageArray[0] == "M")
        {
            lstDisplay.Items.Add(storageArray[1]);

        }

    }

    //label to be used to display the number of students
    lblnoOfStudents.Text = counter.ToString();
    myReader.Close();

}
```

EDIT: I felt like I should improve my answer, so I figured I'd just improve your code.

```
//int counter = 0; may as well move inside as it looks to be localised
private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    using(StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader("StudentRecords.txt"))
    {
        int counter = 0;
         while (!myReader.EndOfStream)
         {
             string[] storageArray = myReader.ReadLine().Split('#');
              switch(storageArray[0])
              {
              case "S":

                   lstDisplay.Items.Add("");
                   lstDisplay.Items.Add("Student Name: " + storageArray[1]);
                   lstDisplay.Items.Add("Student Number: " +storageArray[2]);
                   lstDisplay.Items.Add("Attendance: " + storageArray[5]);
                   lstDisplay.Items.Add("Modules: ");
                   counter++;
                    break;
               case "M":
                     lstDisplay.Items.Add(storageArray[1]);
                    break;
              default:
                    break;
             }
         }
    }

    //label to be used to display the number of students
    lblnoOfStudents.Text = counter.ToString();
    }
}
```

- using will automatically close the reader for you
- `==false` is
  redundant as you can already get a boolean from the left hand side of
  this operator.
- switch statement will make it easy for you to add
  multiple different options instead of a long else if

Comment: Because exactly the same answer was already provided couple minutes earlier.

Comment: I still dont see the same answer. not only did I move counter inside his function as it seems unnecessary to have outside, I have also provided code that could just replace his function

Comment: Great, you've just copied a lot of unnecessary code from question to the answer! Still -1 from me...

Comment: fair enough, I feel I've explained myself

Comment: @Sayse, you should test the code you refactor before suggesting the questioner uses it. Removing `== false` is fine but forgetting to add a `!` operator negates the condition and breaks the code.

Comment: Thanks for the added effort. I can now see the solution using case statements aswel!!